# YACC code support? IDE, plugin, whatever?

Tags: yacc, code-editor

I'm learning YACC and I like to learn new languages having an editor pointing out my errors live.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try xcode,it can compile lex and yacc and you can debug with it.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing. It won't highlight the syntax, but! it is helpful for compiling and debugging, as you said.